# Linux: How to programmatically detect idle threads in a process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Currently a low priority scrubber task is launched periodically in a process. At times due to lock contention this low priority task can interfere with other high priority tasks. I'd like to run such low priority task opportunistically when other threads in the process are idle(blocked waiting for a lock/not running state). I understand that once such low priority task is launched other high priority tasks can start running soon after, however I'm looking to avoid running such low-priority task if other threads in the process are already busy.

Comment: Are you using priority inheritance on your mutexes?  The situation you describe sounds more like priority inversion than simple mutex contention.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to keep track of how many threads are waiting for a task, and running a scrub task if there are at least `x` many waiting threads and if a scrub hasn't been run for `t` time, etc.